# angular-breadcrumb "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! "

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, breadcrumbs

I'm using angular-breadcrumb ,but I want to show it only in some page.
So I write this.

```js
App.controller('crumbCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function (route) {
        return $location.path().indexOf(route)!=-1;
    }
```

```html
       <div ng-controller="crumbCtrl"  ng-show="{true:isActive('model/')}">
            <div  ncy-breadcrumb></div>
        </div>
```

when the page path contains `'model/'`, the page will show it.
but I get an error when entering the page. The error is :

`**Uncaught Error**: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
**Watchers** fired in the last 5 iterations: [["{true:isActive('model/')}; newVal: {\"true\":false}; oldVal: {\"true\":false}"],["{true:isActive('model/')}; ...`

Answer (score 1):

The ng-show directive takes a angular expression returning true or false ("truthy" or "falsy").

Try this :

```
<div ng-controller="crumbCtrl" ng-show="isActive('model/')">
    <div  ncy-breadcrumb></div>
</div>
```